# Bash change Keyboard Back-light (Dell XPS L502X)

Tags: keyboard, xps

I have a Dell XPS 15 L502X. How can I turn On/Off keyboard backlight from terminal or through a bash script?

Comment: This is for an [Asus](https://keramida.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/controlling-the-keyboard-backlight-from-cli/), and doesn't work for my XPS 17 L702X, but perhaps dbus is the way to go.